# What is the best method to make difficut physics movement?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-physics

I want to make a complex system of character movement, with such features as wall crawling, double jumps, etc. and with the further possibility of adding complex elements. I have a choice: 1) I tried to do the movement through rigidbody.velocity changing. But I ran into the following problem: I don’t know how to perform the exact BoxAllCast because I don’t know the exact distance that the body will travel with the changed velocity per frame 2) and using rigidbody.MovePosition is bad because, as I understand it, it does not pass in one frame, but I want have full control over the player, and if you make the controller through rigidbody.velocity changing, then you get a lot of stuck in textures, shaking in textures etc.
Please help me decide, maybe someone can share the sources of a complex movement system so that I can see how they implement it, and generally suggest about the best method for changing the position of a rigidbody

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow!  Note that you may get a better response to this question at https://gamedev.stackexchange.com.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Often complex character controllers won't use the Rigidbody component but instead use a Character Controller component as it provides more control over character movement. Physics accurate controllers are difficult to control as they are controlled by physics. Character controllers allow you to define how physics will work on the controller while also being able to 'force' the player to take certain actions (instead of letting the physics engine do so)

As Tony Li says *"An accurate physics-based model will feel muddy. Players are used to pressing a direction input and seeing their character move immediately without waiting for forces to propagate through the physics simulation. That's why CharacterController exists."* 
https://forum.unity.com/threads/how-to-approach-designing-a-complex-character-controller.345923/#post-2238687